# How to disable secure hash for images via RSS

Tags: facebook, image, rss

I using RSS feed to export facebook posts to blogposts on my website. Some times ago i mentioned there is no preview image for share post. I started to looking the reason of it and it turned out that facebook started to provide images with some secure hash.

Example on such image: https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/10646827_683719278384669_3359388376908609934_n.jpg?oh=29d34b30922c40c1c76faee4455e2225&oe=545D3AF9)

The think is that my share plugin (WP Publicize) is cutting of all pet params from image url and it become unaccessible.

Does anyone now how to disable secure hashes for images on feed?

Thanks forward,
Max.

Comment: You can't remove them. They are there for a reason. Make it so the code you are using are not modifying the urls

Comment: As i wright before it is a plugin code and i can't change it without loosing the possibility to get future updates.

Comment: I would guess it would be easier to fix the bug in WP Publicize than making Facebook change their stuff for no good reason